# Related to regular expressions in Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a string written in some text file -

```
A[B[C[10]]]
```

I need to extract the information of arrays used in this string. Example, I have to store the information in an array,

```
@str = (A[], B[], C[10])
```

I want to accomplish this thing using regex in **Perl**.
I want solution that works for the every case of **array inside array**, like this

```
A[B[C[D[E[F[10]]]]]]
```

So, how to create that `@str` **array**?

Comment: Do you need to handle arrays with more than one element, e.g. `A[1, 2]`? If so, what would the output be?

Comment: Regex are not the right tool for this

Comment: This question lacks the detail needed to give a good answer. Why isn't `10` its own entry?

Comment: Please state your question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern to parse this string recursively, and call Perl code to save intermediate values

Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14;

my @items;
my $i;

my $re = qr{
    ([A-Z]\[)    (?{ $items[$i++] = $^N })
    (?:
        (?R)
        | 
        (\d+)    (?{ $items[$i-1] .= $^N })
    )
    \]           (?{ $items[--$i] .= ']' })
}x;

my $s = 'A[B[C[D[E[F[10]]]]]]';


use Data::Dump;

(@items, $i) = ();
dd \@items if 'A[B[C[10]]]' =~  /$re/g;

(@items, $i) = ();
dd \@items if 'A[B[C[D[E[F[10]]]]]]' =~  /$re/g;
```

#### output

```
["A[]", "B[]", "C[10]"]
["A[]", "B[]", "C[]", "D[]", "E[]", "F[10]"]
```